# How to show hidden button with css media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a hidden button it's means `display:none`. I tried with this.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1360px) {
#a10{display:none;}
#menu_btn{display:block;}
}
```

Comment: When do you want the button to display?

Comment: when display size is 1360px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following code means: "display #menu_btn as inline-block when screen is more or equal to 1360, hide it when screen is less than 1360"

HTML:

```
<input id="menu_btn" type="button"/>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1360px) {
  #menu_btn { display:inline-block; }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1359px) {
  #menu_btn { display:none; }
}
```

PS. remember that you ***cannot*** set inline style in html like this: `<input id="menu_btn" type="button" style="display:none"/>` because it will override style from media query and your button will not be displayed no matter what the screen size will be.